# UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning - Animate UIBezierPath Rounded Rect

Tags: ios, animation, uibezierpath

I am making an animator using the UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning Protocol. During the transition, I want to make the top corners of the Viewcontroller it's transitioning to get rounded. The problem is when I put the following code in the animation-block it doesn't animate.

```
let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 480)    
let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 16, height: 16))
let mask = CAShapeLayer()
mask.path = path.cgPath
self.layer.mask = mask
```

What do I need to do to animate it correctly? I would also like the transition to be interactive in the future.